# strcpy() showing incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Tags: arrays, c, char, strcpy

```c
    char arr[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    char var;

    // Asking input from user
    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < 3; k++)
        {
            if (k % 2 != 0)
            {
                var = get_int("Enter position for x: ");
                strcpy(arr[l][k], "x");
            }
            else
            {
                var = get_int("Enter position for o: ");
                strcpy(arr[l][k], "o");
            }
            design(var, arr);
        }
    }
```

```
arrays/ $ make tictactoe
tictactoe.c:20:24: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
                strcpy(arr[l][k], "x");
                       ^~~~~~~~~
                       &
/usr/include/string.h:141:39: note: passing argument to parameter '__dest' here
extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
                                      ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: tictactoe] Error 1
```

Comment: `arr[l][k]` has type `char`, while `strcpy` requires a `char *` for its first argument.  They are incompatible types.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You initialize `arr` like an array of array of *integers*, not strings, not even characters.

Comment: If you want to copy a single *character*, use character constants a *assignment*. Like `arr[l][k] = 'x';` And initialize your arrays suitable with characters.

Comment: You seem to mix taking alternating moves from the players with iterating over your board.

Comment: You should not be using `strcpy()` — you use single characters, and copying to index 2 in any row with `strcpy()` means writing beyond the end of that row — possibly beyond the end of the array if it's the last row.

Comment: Off-topic: `l` is a horrible choice of variable name because it looks so similar to `1` on many fonts. In this case use either `i`, `j` (idiomatic C) or `x`,`y` (idiomatic math).

Answer (score 4):

`arr` is defined as `char arr[3][3]`, so `arr[l][k]` is a `char`.

`strcpy` expects a `char *`, a pointer to a `char`, and more specifically a pointer to the first of a series of `char` to which it will copy a string (a NUL-terminated sequence of `char` values).

Looks like you want `arr[l][k] = 'x';`.

---

Other issues:

- Does it really make sense to initalize `arr` that way?
- If `k` is the horizontal offset, why do you use it to determine whether `x` or `o` should be used?
- Why isn't `var` used anywhere?
- Why do you attempt to loop over every position?
- Why do you skip the first column when you do?